# How to use preferences in fragment using sherlock action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, preferences

I want to support api level 9 and still using fragments and tabs. Therefor I have used sherlock action bar and it works fine. Now, in one of my tabs (all tabs are fragments) I want to have a settings screen for creating a new game. I figure preferences is the best choice. BUT I don't know how to use preferences in a fragment and still support api level 9. Can anyone please help?
If it's not possible to use preferences in fragment and support api level 9, do you have any suggestions? How can I for example create views to look like a preference, that is, text to the left, checkbox to the right and when I check it, the whole layout gets selected? And a radiobuttongroup with the same look?

Comment: I'm having the same dilema. I need to have a preference fragment but don't want to break support. I recognise the limitations of ActionbarSherlock considering there is no SherlockPreferenceFragment. So I'm guess I'm just going to have to create something that simply looks like the standard preferences layout but is in fact purely custom...